# Stackdriver Trace on GKE 403

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

I have a GKE cluster with "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append" scope enabled.

node.js client library is used as the first line as written in the docs.
I get 403.

`ERROR:@google-cloud/trace-agent: TraceWriter: error:  403
ApiError: The caller does not have permission`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the `trace.append` OAuth scope when creating the cluster as [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/nodejs#container_engine) describe?

```
gcloud container clusters create example-cluster-name --scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append
```